# Show Columns query showing Column Data type not Column Value

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I am trying to use the query :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM @TABLENAME.DB
```

inside html tag like:

```
<input type="text" name="colName" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
```

the output for echo statement is showing the column 'Data Type', for ex - INT(11).

Whereas when I use the same query in a simple php only file, the output of 
$row[n] is the Column Name.

WHY ??

Comment: What is `n`? Please show your PHP code. Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, fetch an associative array instead, so you don't have to remember the order of the columns.

Comment: well n =1 and the code is: $rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee");
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
  echo $rows[1];
  }

Comment: The Column names may be changed in future by the user of the program and so I did not use fetch_assoc()

Comment: You mean the column of your table?

Comment: yes the column of my table, since it is an employee table so the user may change the field names if needed. well , when I change the code to $row[0] it shows the column names. But I want to store each column name inside an array, something like :

Comment: $rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee");
$cols = Array();
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
  ... here I am getting lost ... how to store the values of each col name in the array cols
  }

Comment: @riteshrc You want (by example) `$cols=['id'=>'int(11),'name'=>'varchar(30)];`?

Comment: @riteshrc Or you want `$cols = ['id', 'name', ...]`?

Comment: @Syscall I want $cols[0] = 'id', $cols[1] = 'name', $cols[2] = 'email' ....till the last column, so that when I echo $col[1] it will show "Name" as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the columns of your table change, the columns names of the result come from the query `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table`. But, you could use `mysqli_fetch_array()` to get both:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // print_r($row) ;
    // echo $row['Field'] ; // Name of table column.
    echo $row['Type'] ;
}
```

---

**(last) EDIT**

```
//1. get columns.

$cols = [] ;
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $cols[] = $row['Field'];
}

//2. get values :

$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employee");
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){

    //leftside cols
    $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
    $pdf->SetXY(10,50);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$cols[0]. ":",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10,$code,0,1,'C');

    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$cols[1]. ":",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10,$designation,0,1,'C');

    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$rows[0]. ":",0,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10,$department,0,1,'C');
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of a quote from one of my former coworkers: _"You can explain it to em, but you can't understand it for em."_

Comment: Thank you @Don'tPanic. It is totally true.

Answer (score 0):

this is the final working code :

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM employee");
$cols = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
    $cols[] = $rows[0];
}
//leftside cols
    $pdf->SetFontSize(10);
$pdf->SetXY(10,50);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,$cols[1]. ":",0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$code,0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(50,10,$cols[4]. ":",0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$designation,0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(50,10,$cols[5]. ":",0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$department,0,1,'C');

$pdf->Cell(50,10,"@".$cols[3]. ":",0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$email,0,1,'C');

...........
```